# Swift 4: How to create an array with the most recent emoji used?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out how to get the unicode strings of the most recent emoji like in the messages app to display in a UICollectionView. I have figured out how to put regular emoji into a UICollectionView, and would just need a string array with the most recent emoji used. I tried using the answer from [Access most recently used emojis list in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201296/access-most-recently-used-emojis-list-in-ios) but it returned nil when running on my phone.

Comment: From that answer: "Note that this is **UNDOCUMENTED**, and I have only checked it works on iOS 9 when deployed via Xcode. There is no guarantee that the App Store reviewers will allow this usage, nor there is any guarantee that it will work in the past or future versions."

Comment: It is true that it is undocumented, but snapchat uses the most recent emoji from your phone in their app, and I don't see any other way how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering, I managed to solve the problem for iOS 11 in xcode 9 beta:

```
if let prefs = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.apple.EmojiPreferences") {
        if let defaults = prefs.dictionary(forKey: "EMFDefaultsKey"){
            if let recents = defaults["EMFRecentsKey"] as? [String]{
                emojiList.append(recents)
            }
        }
    }
```

However, like [Access most recently used emojis list in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201296/access-most-recently-used-emojis-list-in-ios), "there is no guarantee that the App Store reviewers will allow this usage, nor there is any guarantee that it will work in the past or future versions."